# How to make MacBook Pro's keyboard backlight fade in and out?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, backlight

I am on a MacBook Pro 13-inch with Big Sur installed in it. I want to know whether there is any third party app or terminal command, which transitions the keyboard backlight from 0 brightness to max brightness and vice versa gradually, like it happens in RGB keyboards.

Thank You.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157878/keyboard-backlit-light-control-from-command-line; especially https://github.com/pirate/mac-keyboard-brightness

Comment: Using the GitHub link code, will it be possible for me to program it myself so that it gradually increases and decreases brightness? Also, I'm only experienced in python, and nothing else, will I be able to do so?

Comment: Sure, write a simple script that runs `kbrightness` in a loop with varying brightness.

Comment: Okay let me try... Also it wouldn't harm in any way, would it?

Comment: I ran `kbrightness` once and it worked for me, but I can't vouch for its safety or anything.

Comment: Can you help me in how I can install it? Like, do I have to install the file using Command Line or Do I have to download the kbrightness file (which I just downloaded) and open it with Python notebooks (JuPyter or PyCharm)?

Comment: Open the Terminal at the folder containing `kbrightness` and run `./kbrightness` and `./kbrightness 0.4`. (Tested in Catalina, not Big Sur.)

Comment: Yes, it works, but how can I write a code using Python (considering I have to gradually increase the brightness level). Like, how do I write it such that it runs the command ./kbrightness every second? I can write a Python code for that, only the running command line script using python is something I haven't done before...

Comment: Perhaps ask in https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reached my goal, and have created a piece of code which makes my keyboard glow like the RGBs.

The Kbrightness file is downloaded from [this](https://github.com/pirate/mac-keyboard-brightness) site. It is stored in the same folder as the python file.

Code involved:

```
import os
from time import sleep

value = 0.00


def change_brightness():
    os.system(f"./kbrightness {value}")


while True:
    while value <= 1.00:
        value +=0.01
        change_brightness()
        sleep(0.01)
        if value == 0.99:
            break
    while value >= 0.00:
        value -=0.01
        change_brightness()
        sleep(0.01)
        if value == 0.01:
            break
```